# google apps script - write data in next empty row

Tags: javascript, java, google-apps-script, google-sheets

with google apps script I am collecting data from other spreadsheet. This is set to collect data daily and writing that in to a sheet “DATABASE”.

So far I have this as a basic solution, but this is always write data and replace the existing data.

In my script I want to copy data from import range spreadsheet to specific column And what I want is continuously to copy the data to the next empty row, but how to do this without erasing existing copied data?. PLEASE HELP!.

```
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var ssid = '1usRuvazJlxAGvF0G2-e00MEQ_AjMCOnWopBFX4qfUcc';
var sheetName = 'DATABASE';

function CopyDatabase() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var startRow = 3;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var Copy = "Copy";
  var newRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    if (row[5] != Copy) {
      var Code = row[0];
      var orderDate = row[1];
      var custName = row[2];

      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 5).setValue(Code);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 6).setValue(orderDate);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 7).setValue(custName);

    }
  }
}
```

Here is the link of database (Google sheet) :

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1usRuvazJlxAGvF0G2-e00MEQ_AjMCOnWopBFX4qfUcc/edit#gid=0
```

[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu4Ld.png)

Comment: I don't see where you have specified the second spreadsheet.

Comment: The whole proses is on one spreadsheet, just in left and right side in worksheet

Comment: Hi! I posted an answer explaining how to do this. I'm not sure whether you want to copy the rows containing `Copy`, or the ones _not_ containing it. Also I'm not sure whether column `D` should be copied or not. In any case, I hope the general idea is clear.

Comment: Hi!, row that contains COPY only as a filter to prevent duplication of data, according to the code, if (row [5]! = Copy) then run the script.

The dynamic data is column A, B and C, and the data base that I want to write down continuously is columns E, F and G without replacing the previous data (Append row)

Comment: @Iamblichus Thanks you very much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to copy the rows from columns `A-D` (where column `D` is not `Copy`) to columns `E-H`, to the first empty row of these target columns.

If that's the case, you can:

- Get the first empty row in columns `E-H` via [getNextDataCell(direction)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNextDataCell(Direction)).
- Filter out the rows not containing `Copy` from the source data, using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- Use [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) to copy the filtered rows to the destination columns (starting at first empty row).

#### Code snippet:

```
function CopyDatabase() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var startRow = 3; 
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - startRow + 1; 
  var startCol = 1;
  var numCols = 4;
  var startColTarget = 5;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCols); 
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); 
  var Copy = "Copy"; 
  var firstEmptyRow = sheet.getRange("E3:H3").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow() + 1;
  var dataToCopy = data.filter(row => row[3] !== Copy);
  sheet.getRange(firstEmptyRow, startColTarget, dataToCopy.length, dataToCopy[0].length).setValues(dataToCopy);
}
```

Comment: @lamblichus.
Hi! You understand what I need correctly. flawless. I've tried this method and it works the way I want, Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

It may be easiest to copy the data to a different tab in the spreadsheet. Try replacing the `for` loop in your code with this:

```
  const targetSheetName = 'Archive of Daily Data';
  const targetSheet = sheet.getParent().getSheetByName(targetSheetName)
    || sheet.getParent().insertSheet(targetSheetName);
  data
    .filter(row => row[3] === Copy)
    .forEach(row => targetSheet.appendRow([row[0], row[1], row[2]]));
```

Comment: Hi! I have tried this method and it works, but what I need is to copy in one worksheet. This code gave me inspiration for different projects. Thanks!